# std::equality_comparable concept checking in a context where private operator == is accessible

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, private, c++-concepts

`std::equality_comparable` allows one to check that class objects can be compared using `==` and `!=` operators. But what shall it return if the operators exist but available not in all contexts?

In the next program `A::operator ==` is private and accessible only in friend function `f`. And if one checks that `std::equality_comparable<A>` is `false` before `f` then it will be false in `f` body as well:

```
#include <concepts>

class A {
    bool operator ==(const A&) const = default;
    friend void f();
};

static_assert( !std::equality_comparable<A> );
void f() {
    static_assert( !std::equality_comparable<A> );
}
```

This is accepted by GCC, Clang, and MSVC, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yqc38zobf

But if one first tests the concept inside `f` then in GCC and Clang it will be `true`, and will remain `true` after `f`:

```
class A {
    bool operator ==(const A&) const = default;
    friend void f();
};

void f() {
    static_assert( std::equality_comparable<A> );
}
static_assert( std::equality_comparable<A> );
```

Only MSVC still considers `std::equality_comparable<A>==false` here, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ko3Kqc9x7

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: @NicolBolas the linked answer contradicts the behavior of both clang & gcc in this case (second example), so there is maybe more to it. [concepts cannot be instanciated and are evaluated as expressions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.concept#5) so one could argue that concepts DO have to consider the context in which they're used, because they behave like expressions. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/5dv6fq1qz) (in one function `CanCompare<A>` is true, in another it is false) - so it would be intuitive if concepts behaved like the requires expression they represent.

Comment: i.e. change the value depending on the context they're used in. My guess would be that all 3 compilers are wrong in the OPs example (although in different ways) - `std::equality_comparable<A>` should be true inside of `f()`, but false outside.

Comment: @Turtlefight: "*the linked answer contradicts the behavior of both clang & gcc in this case*" That just means those compilers are wrong. "*one could argue*" You can argue what you like, but the standard won't back you up. A concept must evaluate to the same value no matter where it appears, and code which does not (perhaps by having different definitions visible before the concept's definition) is ill-formed, NDR.

Comment: @Turtlefight: "*it would be intuitive if concepts behaved like the requires expression they represent*" The committee went to great lengths to ensure that this *wasn't* the case, precisely so that implementations can cache the results of concept evaluations.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh that's too bad, so no concept-shenanigans with friended functions/classes :( Would've been a lot more fun if they were context-sensitive - but you're right they aren't - so clang & gcc are wrong in OP's case, `std::equality_comparable<A>` should always be `false`. But there's still the possibility to use macros to get context-sensitive concepts, e.g. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/en97cn59a) - "macro-concepts" :D I'm not sure if that's a good option though - probably wouldn't use it myself :D

Comment: @Turtlefight, currently in GCC and Clang one can create context-sensitive concepts thanks to your idea and default lambda argument, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fTz11e8TT

Comment: @Fedor but that's due to the compiler bug you reported right? So it might break in the future once they fix the bug - the macro version should be well-defined and be context-sensitive for all compilers (at least i hope so :D )

Comment: @Turtlefight, yes I reported the bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104111 Hopefully it will be fixed soon. But anyway, there are many compiler versions where the trick will work.