# Why does requires-expression behave differently in template and not-template for checking private member access?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-expression

In the following code class `A` has a private member function `f`. I want to write a static assertion that will check whether this function is accessible from the current context (as was suggested in the comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70762249/7325599)).

There are 3 similar cases all based on `requires`-expression:

```
class A{ void f(); };

// #1: accepted by all
static_assert( ![](auto x){ return requires(decltype(x) a){ a.f(); }; }(A{}) );

// #2: rejected by Clang:
static_assert( ![](auto){ return requires(A a){ a.f(); }; }(nullptr) );

// #3: rejected by all
static_assert( ![](void*){ return requires(A a){ a.f(); }; }(nullptr) );
```

The case #3 (and #2 in Clang) is rejected with the error:

```
error: 'f' is a private member of 'A'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mxs4P7x8s

Why does requires-expression behave differently in template and not-template (cases #1 and #3)?
Which compiler is right in #2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#1 describes that

> A requires-expression provides a concise way to express requirements on template arguments

the [grammar of a requires-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#nt:requires-expression)

> ```
> requires-expression:
>   requires requirement-parameter-list(opt) requirement-body
>
> requirement-body:
>   { requirement-seq }
>
> requirement-seq:
>   requirement
>   requirement requirement-seq
>
> requirement:
>   simple-requirement
>   [...]
>
> simple-requirement:
>   expression ;  // A simple-requirement asserts the validity of an expression.
> ```

allows requires-expressions containing arbitrary expressions that do not necessarily depend on template arguments, meaning the following is well-formed:

```
constexpr bool f() { return requires(int a) { a; }; }
constexpr bool g() { return requires { 0; }; }

static_assert(f());
static_assert(g());
```

Thus, for a requires-expression that is declared outside of a templated entity, the same rules as for any expression applies, and `#3` is thus correctly rejected by all compilers (access checking control is not waived in the context of expressions in requires-expressions).

`#1` is also correctly implemented by all compilers, as per https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#5.sentence-2:

> The substitution of template arguments into a requires-expression may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements or the violation of the semantic constraints of those requirements. **In such cases, the requires-expression evaluates to false; it does not cause the program to be ill-formed.**

... as `a.f();` in the constraint expression for the generic `a` substituted as being of type `A` results in an invalid expression, as `f()` is private and not visible.

Finally, `#2` is IFNDR as per https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#5.sentence-6:

> If the substitution of template arguments into a requirement would always result in a substitution failure, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

We could likewise argue that it is IFNDR as per https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#6.4:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed **due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter**, or

Thus, `#2` is correctly implemented by all compilers, but it's arguably always nice when compilers actually do diagnose IFNDR violations, so a usability star for Clang.