# LIFT macro that has std::invoke-like behavior?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I want to have a `LIFT(F)` macro. I can write that easily enough:

```cpp
#define LIFT(F) \
    [&](auto&&... args) \
    noexcept(noexcept((F)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))) \
    -> decltype(auto) { \
        return (F)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
    }
    
// Now you can use `LIFT(std::max)` as a function-object.
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r6bY6P15T

I can similarly write one that calls `F` as a member function on the first argument:

```cpp
#define LIFT_MEMFN(F) \
    [&](auto&& self, auto&&... args) \
    noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<decltype(self)>(self).F(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))) \
    -> decltype(auto) { \
        return std::forward<decltype(self)>(self).F(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1cG5YTY1W

What I would like, and I feel like might be possible with crazy SFINAE tricks but I haven't figured it out, is to write a `LIFT(F)` that acts like `std::invoke`, so if it is passed a first argument, `a0`, first try `a0.F(args...)` then trying `a0->F(args...)`, then falling back to `F(a0, args...)`. Is this possible?

Comment: How about... just calling `std::invoke` in the lambda body?

Comment: Macro? Why? C++ good practice is: do not use macro if only possible! Why you need this macro, what is desired functionality?

Comment: Oh wait... it's `LIFT`, you can't call invoke since the overload set is unresolved yet... ugh. I don't think this is possible. To determine the proper expression, you'd need to resolve the type of the "thing" being lifted. But you can't... otherwise you won't need to lift it to begin with.

Comment: You can test with `if constexpr (requires { ... })`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't think so?: https://godbolt.org/z/v4eTzeKd8 It seems like I need a way to test if `a0.F(args...)` is possible but with a "soft" failure rather than a "hard" failure. (I don't have good words to describe this.)

Comment: @Ben - That's because you misuse the requires expression, the body of the lambda is not the immediate context. You need to check expressions directly https://godbolt.org/z/zxvcjbEbv - While this is a good leap forward, the exception specification being gone is unfortunate.

Comment: Or change `decltype(auto)` by `decltype(fun_body)` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PWxE15fer).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I put the exception specification off for later. That seems like the easy part. :-)
Here's a subproblem I don't understand: I can make a concept to test if `f(T)` is callable, but I don't know a way to do it in-line: https://godbolt.org/z/vPqbsqYvo

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KvddqhxEq gets pretty far!

Comment: @Ben requires expressions don't work with non-dependent constructs (like how `static_assert(false);` used to be wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70783451/5754656 ). An inline way to do it is to make it dependent, like: `static_assert(![]<typename T = S>{ return requires(T x) { f(x); }; }())`

Comment: Cool. This does a decent job encapsulating that: `#define DEPENDENT_REQUIRES(TYPE, NAME, EXPRESSIONS) [&]<typename T = TYPE>{ return requires { [&](T NAME) EXPRESSIONS; }; }()` https://godbolt.org/z/eYPc9MoM7